# Apple script for plist modify not working in MacOS mavericks

Tags: applescript-objc

I just updated my Mac OS to Mavericks and stuck in a issue in my project.

I an updating localization key in plist with apple script. But when I set the localization key plist file goes to 0 KB.

It was working in Mac OS 10.8.

Below is my script to change plist key :

```
 if keyVar as string = "CFBundleLocalizations" then
                        -- Parse the string for delimiter , and get the array of schemes
                        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
                        set theLanguageItems to text items of valVar
                        -- restore delimiters to previous.if not reset then creats error for below code if we have any property below CFBundleLocalizations propert file.
                        set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "="
                        --if there are localization available 
                        if the length of theLanguageItems is greater than 0 then
                            --create structure for CFBundleLocalizations 
                            tell application "System Events"
                                set pFile to property list file plistFile
                                tell pFile
                                    tell contents
                                        --and write to the plist file                                   
                                        --make new property list item with properties {kind:list, value:"theLanguageItems"}
                                        set value of property list item "CFBundleLocalizations" to theLanguageItems
                                    end tell
                                end tell
                            end tell
                        end if
```

Comment: Why are you doing this in AppleScript?

Comment: I have my own tool which generates application from Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mavericks it seems behavior difference for AppleScript, where `set value of property list item` is not working as expected.

One alternate is to use `make new property` that you have commented. In this case a new property will be created and appended to the existing one. Hence you need to be careful for that.

Below is actual solution that works for array list

```
 repeat with theCurrentValue in theLanguageItems
     make new property list item with properties {kind:string, value:theCurrentValue}
 end repeat
```